# GWT call JS method from applet

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, applet

Im trying to call a Javascript method from applet, i read some examples, but nothing works.

Applet :

```
        JSObject window = JSObject.getWindow(this);
        String[] args = new String[]{"some string"};
        window.call("alert2 ", args);
```

GWT, View

```
    public static native void export() /*-{
    $wnd.alert2 = function(result) {
        @cl.covepa.client.main.shared.view.DlgVerificarHuellaView::alert2(Ljava/lang/String;)(result);
    }
}-*/;

public static void alert2(String result) {
    Dialogs.getInstance().alert("CONFIRMACION :" + result);
}
```

and at the constructor call, i test in onModuleLoad  too.

```
export();
```

when the applet run, its say

> No such method "alert2 " on JavaScript object

its ok, i understand the code is obfuscated but i suppose this is the way for the method keep its name, but doesnt works, i still see this on client side

```
function dBb(){$wnd.alert2=function(a){T2c((!S2c&&(S2c=new X2c),S2c),'CONFIRMACION :'+a)}}
```

what i miss ?!, thanks

**UPDATE :**

HTMLPanel contain a HTML object with this String, its add at show DialogBox.

```
<div> 
   <applet id="uploadApplet" code="app.VerifHuella.class" 
           archive="VerificarHuella.jar" width="322" height="465" MAYSCRIPT>
       <param name="RUT" value="15645322"/>
   </applet> 
</div>
```

Comment: Is `alert2` defined in JS global scope when you call it from the applet?

Comment: You might be looking for using https://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/

Comment: Do you obfuscate GWT code during compilation?

Comment: SSR im trying to do on this way, but if doesnt work i will use it.   user592704 obfuscate is default work of GWT right?, so yes. VisioN, above is all my code, maybe i miss something but, i think its should be simple.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your problem is that the method is not available in the window when you call it. It could happen because three reasons:

- Your appled run before the async loading of the gwt permutation happened.
- You are not calling your `export()` method in your `onModuleLoad()`
- Your alert2 method is not static

Anyway, if you wanted to export classes and methods without using a single line of jsni you could try [gwtexporter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/), in your case your code could look like:

```
 class DlgVerificarHuellaView implements Exportable {
    @Export($wnd.alert2)
    public static void alert2(String msg) {
    }
 }
```

Another nice way to export a funcion without writing jsni is using [gwtquery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/):

```
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*

Properties wnd = window.cast();
wnd.setFunction("alert2", new Function() {
  public void f() {
    Properties arg = getDataProperties();
    DlgVerificarHuellaView.alert2(arg.get(0));
  }
});
```

Comment: `window` is a static variable in GQuery. So the `import static ...GQuery.*` does the magic